# Github account loosing contribution graph in different scenarios

Tags: github, organization

I have some doubts regarding how **Github** manages E-mails associated with organizations

Next I am going to present the different scenarios that I could face:

1. ***I am removed from organization A:*** Will I lose all my contributions
   in the github graph? If so, is there any way to keep them?
2. ***I have 2 E-mails associated with my Github account:***
   **Corporate (Primary)**
   **Personal one**
   If I change company and remove the E-mail from Github preferences.
   Will I lose all the contributions associated with the corporate E-mail and will
   they disappear from the Github graph? If so, is there any way to keep
   them ?

I find it very strange to lose all contributions in any of the cases mentioned
above So what is the point of having a history of **commits**/**Pull Requests**
that we are going to "lose"? I fully understand that I am not the owner of the
repositories, but it is work that is not being reflected in the future, although at some
point I have been a contributor to it.